# Label Text Autosize(fontSize) in Flex Mobile App

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Is there a way to autosize the fontSize of the text in a label component in a Flex mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

The text automatically scales depending on the device's resolution.

See for example here [enter link description here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c682e5a9412cf5976c17-8000.html): "Text The font size of text (not the text itself) is scaled to match the resolution."